# filter and retrieve the first element with jq

Tags: linux, jq

Consider the following json:

```
{"document": "test", "data" : [{"color" : "blue", "person" : "john"},
                               {"color" : "red", "person" : []},
                               {"color" : "purple", "person" : "alice"}]}
```

I am trying to use `jq` to filter on the `.data.person` elements and return the first `.data` item with a non-null `person`.
The following does not seem to work:

```
jq '.data[]' myjson | jq select(.person!= "") | jq '.[0]'
```

What is the proper way to do so? output should be:

```
{'color' : 'blue', 'person' : 'john'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, fixed in the example, thanks! do you know which query I should run then?

Comment: done! added an empty list instead of a empty string too

Answer (score 1):

The JSON key/value pairs need to be double quoted with `"`, for the jq parser to interpret them. Fix your JSON before running with through jq

You can use the `first/1` built-in to perform this,

```
first(.data[]? | select(.person | length > 0))
```

demo - [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/rX9nXhSRZGB)

Comment: could you please point me to the docs for the `.data?` syntax please? I knew that .data[] would iterate over the elements in the list but what is the ? for?

Comment: The jq manual is one place to look-up - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.[]?